# JAVA - Menu running in loop - How can I print out all choices?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to learn JAVA and I'm working on a simple pizza order assignment running purely in text/console format.

I've made the user chose a pizza, but they need the option to add extra ingredients.

My thought was to use a for loop to show a toppings menu and then ask for a numbered input matching the ingredient they want to add.

I want them to be able to select several ingredients, why I'm doing it in a loop.

My code as of now looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; ingredientInput>0; i++ ){
            toppingsMenu();
            ingredientInput = ingredientScan.nextInt();
            ingredientScan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Type your choice here:");
        }
        System.out.println(ingredientInput);
```

Everything works great, but I'd like to add a system.out.println() telling the user, what they've chosen as:

*"You've added extra cheese - Would you like to add more?"*
If so, I would like to expand that sentence: *"You've added extra cheese & pepperoni - Would you like to add more?"*

Could you help me by pointing me in a direction that might work? I'm not into any object related part of JAVA yet, purely text-based so far.

Thanks.

**Solution provided by Adeel Ahmad**

```
ArrayList<Integer> ingredients = new ArrayList<>(); 
for (int i = 0; ingredientInput>0; i++ ){
        toppingsMenu();
        ingredientInput = ingredientScan.nextInt();
        ingredientScan.nextLine();
        ingredients.add(ingredientInput);
        System.out.println("Type your choice here:");
    }
    System.out.println(ingredientInput);
```

Looking back it's so interesting to see which problems I struggled to solve, as now, a few months later, this seems so basic. But thanks anyway to everyone who helped :D

Comment: I recommend you to use HashMap(numberOfIngredient, nameOfIngredient) to store/show the ingredients. Take a look of how to use HashMap https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Which difficulties are you facing? You could add that in your loop and end the loop if the user selects "no". For the formatting you'd need to store the selected ingredients and use that to build the ouput "You've added extra [ingredients here] - Would you like to add more?".

Comment: Btw, since you're not using the `i` variable you could replace your for-loop with a while: `while( ingredientInput > 0 )` - or maybe even `while(true) { ... if( ingredientInput == 0 ) { break; } } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to be able to store all the added ingredients in data container (e.g `ArrayList`or `HashMap`). Whenever user inputs an ingredient, just added that in your `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<Integer> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; ingredientInput>0; i++ ){
            toppingsMenu();
            ingredientInput = ingredientScan.nextInt();
            ingredientScan.nextLine();
            ingredients.add(ingredientInput);
            System.out.println("Type your choice here:");
        }
        System.out.println(ingredientInput);
```

Once you have collected all the user selected ingredients in your `ArrayList`, you can then iterate over it in a loop and construct your final message.

Comment: Pleasure, please consider up-voting the answer if it helped ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
String orderedSoFar = "";
boolean done = false;
do {
    // read next ingredient from user
    String currentIngredient = scanner.nextLine();
    // if first extra ingredient
    if(orderedSoFar.equals("")){
        orderedSoFar += currentIngredient;
    // if not first extra ingredient
    } else {
         orderedSoFar += " & " + currentIngredient;
    }
    System.out.println("Ingredients so far " + orderedSoFar);
    System.out.println("Add more extra ingredients?");
    // read choice to continue or not from user
    done = Boolean.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
}while(!done);
```